# Find table_name that contains two known column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the tables that contain both of the two columns together in one table. I tried this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME in ('CurrencyName', 'CurrencyKey');
```

This query generates all the tables that has either one of the `CurrencyName` or `CurrencyKey` column.

But I want the table that has both of these columns together.

Please shoot some ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  You want to use `group by` and then validate that you have two matches using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME in ('CurrencyName', 'CurrencyKey')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Note:  To be sure you have the right table, you should use `TABLE_SCHEMA` as well in the query.